# Como obtengo 2 Array con .map y usarlo en una sola variable

Tags: nodejs

```
 try {

   const result = await res1.json();
   Object.values(result.stats[0].escolar).forEach((data) => {
   console.log(data);
         });
        let todosnombres = result.stats[0].escolar.map(a => a.name).join("\n")
        let todosid = result.stats[0].escolar.map(a => a.id).join("cm\n")

           const infolugar = new MessageEmbed()

             .setColor("#8000ff")
             .setAuthor(`${nombre}`)
             .setDescription(`Lista con calificaciones de **${nombre}**.`)  
             .addFields(
                { name: 'Nombre', value: `${todosnombres}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Tamaño', value: `${todosid}cm`, inline: true }
                       )
                 message.channel.send(infolugar)
```

El resultado termina así visto desde PC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en Celular se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que se muestre todo como la versión en PC

Comment: Tu problema me huele mucho más a temas responsivos y de estilos que de lógica... podrías incluir el código de la vista que estas usando?

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente creo que tu problema es más por estilos, sin embargo contestando a tu pregunta... puedes hacer un arreglo de la siguiente manera

```
let data = result.stats[0].escolar.map(a => ({
    name: a.name,
    id: a.id
}))
```

Esto te regresa un arreglo con los nombres y ida tipo `[{name: 'Materia', id: '12.5'},{name: 'Materia', id: '22.8'}]`

Espero sea útil

Comment: puede ser una forma que pueda usarla. Pero como coloco esto en la descripcion del embed?
Lo habia colocado asi
.setDescription(` ${todosnombres}`)

Pero me sale como mensaje:
[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

tal como me explicó David.

```
let data = result.stats[0].escolar.map(a => ({
    name: a.name,
    id: a.id
}))
```

pero solo obtengo en el mensaje y en consola

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

Pero si solo trato de obtener una

```
let data = result.stats[0].fish.map(a => a.name).join("\n")
```

Si obtengo el resultado deseado.

Entonce como obtengo name y el id? Mi idea es que salga junto ambos.

- Name ID
- Name ID
- Name ID

Comment: Es una respuesta o parte de la pregunta¿

Answer (score 0):

**data** es un arreglo, para acceder a el se puede utilizar un for, aquí falta información de como es que estas presentando el contenido, ya que solo veo funciones que estas agregando y no se como funciona, que parámetros necesita la función y como es que se utiliza.

En un 'renderizado' básico se puede hacer de la siguiente forma (en el front-end)

```
document.write('<div id="elemento"></div>')
elemento = document.getElementById('elemento')
data.forEach(item => {
    var p = document.createElement('p') // Aqui se crea un elemento para agregarlo al div
    p.append(item.name + ': ' + item.id) // Aquí accedes a los valores
    elemento.appendChild(p) // Aquí se agrega el elemento en forma de p
})
```

Como comento, este ejemplo solo es para ver como acceder al arreglo **data** para obtener los valores almacenados. Si estas utilizando un algún template para el renderizado, estos pueden incluir funciones para ciclos. Por ejemplo angular tiene su directiva ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <p>{{item.name}}: {{item.id}}</p>
</div>
```